# Model in Xtext an enumaration type?

Tags: eclipse, model, xtext, ecore

I have created my ecore model:

[image]

I have specified it in my xtext file:

```
MinRequirementsType returns MinRequirementsType:
    'MinRequirementsType'
```

Next I want to implement the rule, but when I try

```
enum minrequire: 0|1 ;
```

I get a mistake!

How is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enum declaration is wrong. Try the following:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model: test+=Test*;

enum OneOrZero: one = '1' | zero = '0';

Test returns Test: value = OneOrZero;
```

Regards,

Xavier